# Are there any libraries for efficiently editing large strings in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, text

I need to efficiently edit large text documents (eg, source code files) in javascript.

`insertAtPosition(n, str)` and `deleteAtPosition(n, length)` must be fast.

A naive string implementation is slow because each operation requires copying the contents of the document to a new string.

There are a few efficient ways to do this. I could use an array of lines ([Ace](http://ace.ajax.org/) aka Bespin does this), but this would be slow when there are super long lines or many short lines. A better implementation would use [skip lists](http://igoro.com/archive/skip-lists-are-fascinating/) or some other clever data structure.

But, I would expect somebody to have implemented such a thing already.

Are there any libraries which already do this? I can't seem to find anything useful with Google - is there a common name for this algorithm problem?

Comment: Try ropes: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29

Comment: Perhaps use `source.split('')` to break it into characters, then use the native Array.splice, which is O(n) at worst.

Comment: @Reid: Naive manipulation of strings is already O(n), so that would not achieve anything.  If arrays in Javascript have per-element memory overheads, your approach will actually be slower.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: naive string manipulation does not include a utility for insertion of characters at a given point, since strings are immutable.

Comment: @Reid: I understand that -- what I'm saying is that "modifying" an immutable string (by creating a new, changed copy) is O(n), the same as your proposed approach, assuming memory can be allocated in constant time. Inserting/deleting a character anywhere in the string will require a memory allocation, followed by all n characters being copied into the new immutable string. Your Array.splice() could be faster if you are inserting/deleting near the end and happen not to require a memory reallocation, because then only characters after that point will need to be copied, but it remains O(n).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are any other libraries to do this, so I implemented it myself using skip lists. It might be faster to use a tree data structure, but skip lists are easy to implement and the closure compiled javascript is only 2.5 KB.

If there's anyone else with the same problem, enjoy:

https://github.com/josephg/jumprope